# What is the name of this type of function composition?

Tags: functional-programming, mathematical-foundations, category-theory

If standard function composition is defined as:

```
 (define compose
   { (B → C) → (A → B) 
             → (A → C) }

   F G -> (λ X (F (G X))))
```

What type of composition does the below function describe? Is there a particular name for it in category theory?

```
 (define compose-2
   { (A → (X → C)) → (B → X)
                   → (A → B → C) }

   F G -> (λ Y (compose (F Y) G)))
```

[image: composition diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You composition is of type $\operatorname{comp}:(A \to X \to C)\to (B \to X) \to (A\to B \to C)$. Up to [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), it can be seen as being of type $(A  \times X \to C)\to (B \to X) \to (A\times B \to C)$. So it's just a composition of a two arguments functions with a one argument function. You take $f$ and $g$ and return $(a,b)\mapsto f(a,g(b))$.

From a general abstract nonsense point of view, you can define the functor $$A\times -:\begin{array}{lll}
O & \mapsto &A\times O\\
g : B \to X&\mapsto &<\operatorname{id}_A;g>:A\times B \to A\times X
\end{array}$$
and then your composition is just $\operatorname{comp}=f\mapsto g \mapsto f\circ (A\times  g)$.